# SQL /php LEFT JOIN - Only display one instance

Tags: php, sql

I am using the following query which works great but I need a modification to it.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `table1` LEFT JOIN 
        `table2` ON table1.messageid=table2.messageid 
WHERE   `venue_active` = 1
```

My problem here is that I `table2.messageid` might have more than 1 match and I only what 1 displayed, but I still want all the records on table1 to be returned.

For example:

`table1.messageid` might have lots of children on Table2 and I only need 1 displayed

How can I do this?

UPDATE: I've tried adding: GROUP BY table1.messageid but it returns nothing.

Comment: don't do select *, specifiy the actual columns you want and if you want to only select where table2.messageid is multiple just do select distinct tbl2.messageid as the first part of your select clause

Comment: if `GROUP BY` returns nothing, then your actual statement doesn't return anything either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `group by` clause

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `table1` LEFT JOIN 
        `table2` ON table1.messageid=table2.messageid 
WHERE   `venue_active` = 1
GROUP BY table1.messageid
```

Comment: I've tried adding: GROUP BY table1.messageid but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

just add `group by`

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `table1` LEFT JOIN 
        `table2` ON table1.messageid=table2.messageid 
WHERE   `venue_active` = 1
GROUP BY table1.messageid
```

Comment: I'd group by `table1.messageid`, but otherwise this is *the* solution.

Comment: @GolezTrol: by `id`, i just mean the `PK` of table`

Comment: I've tried adding: GROUP BY table1.messageid but it returns nothing.

Comment: @Satch3000 That's not possible. `GROUP BY` can decrease the number of results, but it cannot bring it back to `0` if you had results before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your exact tables but this is the equivilent of your query running off a couple of my tables which are 1:many relationships tblusers being your table1 and tblmessages being your table2

```
SELECT tblusers.ID FROM `tblusers` LEFT JOIN tblmessages ON tblusers.ID=tblmessages.recipient_user_id WHERE tblmessages.state=1
```

This returns this
[image]

If I now change the query to be this

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblusers.ID FROM `tblusers` LEFT JOIN tblmessages ON tblusers.ID=tblmessages.recipient_user_id WHERE tblmessages.state=1
```

I now get a unique list of all users which have at least one message in my messages table.

[image]